# SQL Query to Match Between Rows and Columns

Tags: sql, database, join

I have a table with a column called ID1 and a column called ID2. I want to collapse all rows where ID1 is ID2 in another row that also has ID1 as ID2. So basically this before the query is ran:

```
ID1  ID2
34  45
45  32
76  12
13  25
```

Would be this after the query is ran:

```
ID1  ID2
34   45
76  12
13  25
```

I've tried tons of options and I'm getting extremely frustrated. All of my solutions are so broken but start something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM USERS u1 INNER JOIN USERS u2 WHERE u1.ID1 = u2.ID2 and ....
```

Answer (score 2):

Using ANSI SQL, you have at least following options

**Using NOT EXISTS**

```
SELECT *
FROM   USERS u1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM USERS u2 WHERE u2.ID1 = u1.ID2)
```

**Using a LEFT JOIN**

```
SELECT *
FROM   USERS u1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN USERS u2 ON u2.ID1 = u1.ID2
WHERE  u2.ID1 IS NULL
```

and depending on your DBMS there are might be other

pe. [EXCEPT](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/the-except-and-intersect-operators-in-sql-server/) using SQL Server or [MINUS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm) using Oracle

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID1
FROM  USERS 
WHERE  ID1 NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID2 FROM USERS);
```